# SMB administrative Shares (C$) not accessible on a server running SharePoint - WebDAV MiniRedir reports PROPFIND not implemented

Tags: error, webdav

Cross-posted from [http://serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/95632/smb-administrative-shares-c-not-accessible-on-a-server-running-sharepoint-we)

We have a SharePoint 2007 server (Windows 2003) for development which fails to provide access via SMB administrative shares like \server\c$. I can use \mywin7\c$ backwards from a terminal session on that server.

Looking at the packets I see that the \server\share requests are handled by IIS 6 which renders http status 501 Not Implemented in response to PROPFIND verb WebDAV requests.

> PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1 Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent:
>   Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600 Depth: 0 translate: f
>   Content-Length: 0 Host: server
>
> HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented Content-Length: 0 Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2009
>   08:03:25 GMT

How can I force the use of SMB over HTTP/WebDAV for such requests?

SMB Tree Connect AndX Request, Path: \host\c$

Comment: I would also add a 'services-running' (for the sake of autocomplete hinting), a 'unc-path' and a 'shares' tag here or something like that

Comment: Thanks for your tag suggestions and contributions to the site so far! The number of tags for a question is limited to 5 so we can only add one more. I'm going with `shares` as it seems most likely to be used by others.

Comment: Well, then the question isn't specific for the 2007 version of 
SharePoint. We could replace that one with the 'unc-path' and append that the UNC paths pertaining to SharePoint DO WORK without the 'Server' service running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the "Server" service using services.msc renders UNC paths working again.